Does there exist an analytical expression for the formula for the Gaussian PDF of random matrix?
Suppose a random variable $X$ is distributed according to a Gaussian PDF, then I can analytically write:
$$x \sim f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_x^2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{\left(x-\mu_x\right)^2}{2\sigma_x^2}\right\}$$
Suppose a random vector $X$ is distribued according to a Gaussian PDF, then I can analytical write:
$$x \sim f_{\mathbf x}(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\, =
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{k/2}|\boldsymbol\Sigma_x|^{1/2}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu_x})^T{\boldsymbol\Sigma_x}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\boldsymbol\mu_x})
\right)$$
My question is: what if $X$ is a random matrix? then how can I write $f_X(x)$?
Just for fun: what if $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n \times n}$ or more?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution
